# React createContext promise types with typescript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

So, i'm using firebase to sign in with email link. I want in the context file to check for the link then sign in like this:

```
const defaultValue = {};

interface AuthContextInterface {
  SignInWithLink: (email: string | null) => {};
}

const UserContext = createContext<AuthContextInterface>(
  defaultValue as AuthContextInterface
);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const SignInWithLink = (email: string) =>
    signInWithEmailLink(auth, email, window.location.href)
      .then((result) => {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("emailForSignIn");
        console.log("RESULT", result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERRORRrr", error);
      });

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={SignInWithLink}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

and in the component i'm calling the function like this:

```
const { SignInWithLink } = UserAuth();

  if (isSignInWithEmailLink(auth, window.location.href)) {
    let email = window.localStorage.getItem("emailForSignIn");
  
    SignInWithLink(email);
  }
```

When i hover over the `value` in `<UserContext.Provider value={SignInWithLink}` i get this error:

```
Type '(email: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'AuthContextInterface'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(328, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<AuthContextInterface>'
```

I'm new to typescript so please anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`value={SignInWithLink}` has no field called SignInWithLink, as per your interface.
Instead use `value={{SignInWithLink}}>`

Comment: What a silly mistake was this that i didn't see the double curly braces! Even though only this didn't solve my issue, however it led me to more understandable errors and i made it work (somehow lol) just to stop typescript yelling, at least. Thanks!